# Retrieving multiple rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a list of hand listed uniqueID that I want to retrieve from my MySQL database. As of now, I'm using:

```
Select * from TABLE where uniqueID = "111" or uniqueID = "124" or uniqueID = "220"...
```

Obviously this is very time consuming. The list of uniqueID is not written in any file. I just want more efficient query to tell the database to retrieve the rows with the uniqueIDs. Is there something like,

```
Select * from TABLE where uniqueID = {"111", "124", "220"...}
```

that I could use?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT * from table WHERE uniqueID IN (111,123,220);`

Answer (score 3):

```
Select * from TABLE where uniqueID IN ('111','124','220',...)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I also want to know how I can retrieve multiple rows for "like" queries. For instance, I want to do:

select * from table where content like "%as long as%" or content like "%from%" ...

Comment: @JinaHuh: Assuming this answered your original question, please mark this answer as accepted by clicking on the outlined check box next to it. As for your follow up, there's no shorthand to circumvent the multiple ORs for a LIKE.

Comment: Thanks Joe. I didn't know about the check. Sorry!